# Rails carrierwave multiple file upload Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in ArticlesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I was used rails `gem carrierwave` test multiple upload images

below is I'm step by step

- `rails new TestUploadImages`
- `rails g Article title:string body:text`
- `rails generate uploader Avatar`
- `rails g migration add_avatar_to_users avatar:string
   rake db:migrate`

config `Article model uploader`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

config `_form.html.erb` for create article with image

```
<%= form_for @article, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.file_field :avatars%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

`article_controller`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    render "show"
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private 

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :avatar)
  end
end
```

**over here could have create one image with article**

below is try create multiple images

- change `article` table `avatar` column with `avatars`

change `_form.html.erb`

```
<p>
    <%= f.file_field :avatars, multiple: true%>
</p>
```

because my used test db is sqlite3 so, references from [cariierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  serialize :avatars, JSON
end
```

change articles_controller strong parameters

```
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, {avatars: []})
  end
```

now should create multiple images

when I'm trying create found this error

[image]

and terminal message
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In model `Article` mount `avatars` not `avatar`

and change your column `avatar` to:

```
def change
    remove_column :articles, :avatar
    add_column :articles, :avatars, :string, array: true, default: []
end
```